CUPS web interface present, but admin panel is missing
When I browse to http://localhost:631/ I get a web interface to CUPS.
When I then click on Administration, I get Not Found.
The URL http://localhost:631/admin is missing.
I am not able to add a printer, nor am I able to add a printer via the settings app.
It says "No Printers Found" and typing in the IP of my printer leaves me with the UI hanging in:

I am on Ubuntu 24.04 LTS, with cups 2.4.7-1.2ubuntu7.2
$ sudo systemctl status cups
● cups.service - CUPS Scheduler
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/cups.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Fri 2024-08-09 14:47:55 PDT; 1h 2min ago
TriggeredBy: ● cups.socket
             ● cups.path
       Docs: man:cupsd(8)
   Main PID: 1616 (cupsd)
     Status: "Scheduler is running..."
      Tasks: 2 (limit: 96127)
     Memory: 16.8M (peak: 108.9M)
        CPU: 3.192s
     CGroup: /system.slice/cups.service
             ├─1616 /usr/sbin/cupsd -l
             └─1665 /usr/lib/cups/notifier/dbus dbus://

Aug 09 14:47:55 deca systemd[1]: Starting cups.service - CUPS Scheduler...
Aug 09 14:47:55 deca systemd[1]: Started cups.service - CUPS Scheduler.

This is my configuration for cupsd:
#
# Configuration file for the CUPS scheduler.  See "man cupsd.conf" for a
# complete description of this file.
#

# Log general information in error_log - change "warn" to "debug"
# for troubleshooting...
LogLevel warn
PageLogFormat

# Specifies the maximum size of the log files before they are rotated.  The value "0" disables log rotation.
MaxLogSize 0

# Default error policy for printers
ErrorPolicy retry-job

# Only listen for connections from the local machine.
Listen localhost:631
Listen /run/cups/cups.sock

# Show shared printers on the local network.
Browsing On
BrowseLocalProtocols dnssd

# Default authentication type, when authentication is required...
DefaultAuthType Basic

# Web interface setting...
WebInterface Yes

# Restrict access to the server...
<Location />
  Order allow,deny
</Location>

# Restrict access to the admin pages...
<Location /admin>
  Order allow,deny
</Location>

# Restrict access to configuration files...
<Location /admin/conf>
  AuthType Default
  Require user @SYSTEM
  Order allow,deny
</Location>

# Restrict access to log files...
<Location /admin/log>
  AuthType Default
  Require user @SYSTEM
  Order allow,deny
</Location>

# Set the default printer/job policies...
<Policy default>
  # Job/subscription privacy...
  JobPrivateAccess default
  JobPrivateValues default
  SubscriptionPrivateAccess default
  SubscriptionPrivateValues default

  # Job-related operations must be done by the owner or an administrator...
  <Limit Create-Job Print-Job Print-URI Validate-Job>
    Order deny,allow
  </Limit>

  <Limit Send-Document Send-URI Hold-Job Release-Job Restart-Job Purge-Jobs Set-Job-Attributes Create-Job-Subscription Renew-Subscription Cancel-Subscription Get-Notifications Reprocess-Job Cancel-Current-Job Suspend-Current-Job Resume-Job Cancel-My-Jobs Close-Job CUPS-Move-Job CUPS-Get-Document>
    Require user @OWNER @SYSTEM
    Order deny,allow
  </Limit>

  # All administration operations require an administrator to authenticate...
  <Limit CUPS-Add-Modify-Printer CUPS-Delete-Printer CUPS-Add-Modify-Class CUPS-Delete-Class CUPS-Set-Default CUPS-Get-Devices>
    AuthType Default
    Require user @SYSTEM
    Order deny,allow
  </Limit>

  # All printer operations require a printer operator to authenticate...
  <Limit Pause-Printer Resume-Printer Enable-Printer Disable-Printer Pause-Printer-After-Current-Job Hold-New-Jobs Release-Held-New-Jobs Deactivate-Printer Activate-Printer Restart-Printer Shutdown-Printer Startup-Printer Promote-Job Schedule-Job-After Cancel-Jobs CUPS-Accept-Jobs CUPS-Reject-Jobs>
    AuthType Default
    Require user @SYSTEM
    Order deny,allow
  </Limit>

  # Only the owner or an administrator can cancel or authenticate a job...
  <Limit Cancel-Job CUPS-Authenticate-Job>
    Require user @OWNER @SYSTEM
    Order deny,allow
  </Limit>

  <Limit All>
    Order deny,allow
  </Limit>
</Policy>

# Set the authenticated printer/job policies...
<Policy authenticated>
  # Job/subscription privacy...
  JobPrivateAccess default
  JobPrivateValues default
  SubscriptionPrivateAccess default
  SubscriptionPrivateValues default

  # Job-related operations must be done by the owner or an administrator...
  <Limit Create-Job Print-Job Print-URI Validate-Job>
    AuthType Default
    Order deny,allow
  </Limit>

  <Limit Send-Document Send-URI Hold-Job Release-Job Restart-Job Purge-Jobs Set-Job-Attributes Create-Job-Subscription Renew-Subscription Cancel-Subscription Get-Notifications Reprocess-Job Cancel-Current-Job Suspend-Current-Job Resume-Job Cancel-My-Jobs Close-Job CUPS-Move-Job CUPS-Get-Document>
    AuthType Default
    Require user @OWNER @SYSTEM
    Order deny,allow
  </Limit>

  # All administration operations require an administrator to authenticate...
  <Limit CUPS-Add-Modify-Printer CUPS-Delete-Printer CUPS-Add-Modify-Class CUPS-Delete-Class CUPS-Set-Default>
    AuthType Default
    Require user @SYSTEM
    Order deny,allow
  </Limit>

  # All printer operations require a printer operator to authenticate...
  <Limit Pause-Printer Resume-Printer Enable-Printer Disable-Printer Pause-Printer-After-Current-Job Hold-New-Jobs Release-Held-New-Jobs Deactivate-Printer Activate-Printer Restart-Printer Shutdown-Printer Startup-Printer Promote-Job Schedule-Job-After Cancel-Jobs CUPS-Accept-Jobs CUPS-Reject-Jobs>
    AuthType Default
    Require user @SYSTEM
    Order deny,allow
  </Limit>

  # Only the owner or an administrator can cancel or authenticate a job...
  <Limit Cancel-Job CUPS-Authenticate-Job>
    AuthType Default
    Require user @OWNER @SYSTEM
    Order deny,allow
  </Limit>

  <Limit All>
    Order deny,allow
  </Limit>
</Policy>

# Set the kerberized printer/job policies...
<Policy kerberos>
  # Job/subscription privacy...
  JobPrivateAccess default
  JobPrivateValues default
  SubscriptionPrivateAccess default
  SubscriptionPrivateValues default

  # Job-related operations must be done by the owner or an administrator...
  <Limit Create-Job Print-Job Print-URI Validate-Job>
    AuthType Negotiate
    Order deny,allow
  </Limit>

  <Limit Send-Document Send-URI Hold-Job Release-Job Restart-Job Purge-Jobs Set-Job-Attributes Create-Job-Subscription Renew-Subscription Cancel-Subscription Get-Notifications Reprocess-Job Cancel-Current-Job Suspend-Current-Job Resume-Job Cancel-My-Jobs Close-Job CUPS-Move-Job CUPS-Get-Document>
    AuthType Negotiate
    Require user @OWNER @SYSTEM
    Order deny,allow
  </Limit>

  # All administration operations require an administrator to authenticate...
  <Limit CUPS-Add-Modify-Printer CUPS-Delete-Printer CUPS-Add-Modify-Class CUPS-Delete-Class CUPS-Set-Default>
    AuthType Default
    Require user @SYSTEM
    Order deny,allow
  </Limit>

  # All printer operations require a printer operator to authenticate...
  <Limit Pause-Printer Resume-Printer Enable-Printer Disable-Printer Pause-Printer-After-Current-Job Hold-New-Jobs Release-Held-New-Jobs Deactivate-Printer Activate-Printer Restart-Printer Shutdown-Printer Startup-Printer Promote-Job Schedule-Job-After Cancel-Jobs CUPS-Accept-Jobs CUPS-Reject-Jobs>
    AuthType Default
    Require user @SYSTEM
    Order deny,allow
  </Limit>

  # Only the owner or an administrator can cancel or authenticate a job...
  <Limit Cancel-Job CUPS-Authenticate-Job>
    AuthType Negotiate
    Require user @OWNER @SYSTEM
    Order deny,allow
  </Limit>

  <Limit All>
    Order deny,allow
  </Limit>
</Policy>

What is wrong with my CUPS?
Update
I don't have apparmor DENIED entries, but did notice assertion failures:
$ sudo journalctl -f
Aug 09 16:07:34 deca gnome-shell[2601]: Window manager warning: Buggy client sent a _NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW message with a timestamp of 0 for 0xa00004
Aug 09 16:07:37 deca dbus-daemon[1191]: [system] Activating service name='org.opensuse.CupsPkHelper.Mechanism' requested by ':1.336' (uid=1000 pid=12678 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-control-center" label="unconfined") (using servicehelper)
Aug 09 16:07:37 deca dbus-daemon[1191]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.opensuse.CupsPkHelper.Mechanism'
Aug 09 16:07:37 deca cups-pk-helper-[12750]: g_variant_new_array: assertion 'child_type == NULL || g_variant_type_is_definite (child_type)' failed
Aug 09 16:07:37 deca kernel: traps: cups-pk-helper-[12750] trap int3 ip:70a2859e40df sp:7ffe68aecbe0 error:0 in libglib-2.0.so.0.8000.0[70a2859a0000+a0000]
Aug 09 16:07:37 deca cups-pk-helper-[12750]: g_variant_get_type: assertion 'value != NULL' failed
Aug 09 16:07:37 deca cups-pk-helper-[12750]: g_variant_type_is_subtype_of: assertion 'g_variant_type_check (type)' failed
Aug 09 16:07:37 deca cups-pk-helper-[12750]: g_variant_get_type_string: assertion 'value != NULL' failed
Aug 09 16:07:37 deca cups-pk-helper-[12750]: g_variant_new: expected GVariant of type 'a{ss}' but received value has type '(null)'
Aug 09 16:07:37 deca gnome-control-c[12678]: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Message recipient disconnected from message bus without replying


So... the solution:
$ sudo apt install apparmor-utils
$ sudo aa-complain cupsd

